# Different results with SAME Deep learning model for same images

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I am trying to input a deep learning model for pictures.

```py
model = pickle.load(open(finalized_model, 'rb')) #input Learned model

def predict(v_model):
  with torch.no_grad():
    for data, mask in valid_dataloader:、
        data = torch.autograd.Variable(data, volatile=True).cuda() #input raw image
        mask = torch.autograd.Variable(mask, volatile=True).cuda() #input mask image
        result = v_model(data) #disicion raw image
        break
```

If I input image datasets [a,b,c] and [b,c,d] respectively for this code, I can get results [A,B,C] and [B',C',D'].
For some reason, B≠B', C≠C'.

Please tell me when you know why.

Using google colaboratory with pytorch for predict of pre-trained RCNN model.
But I get different results with the same models

Comment: What is the pretrained model? It seems Faster-rcnn

Comment: Sorry, I put the tab incorrectly. FCN in pytorch is used for this code.

Comment: Is difference significant between predictions? I would assume that exact bit-wise equality is not really achievable, so "(C0 == C1) != True" in general case. If the model outputs completely different predictions (different classes, bboxes) - then it becomes interesting